# Spring MVC -> dependent on URL display welcome page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, viewcontroller

I have a Spring MVC application (version 3.0.5.RELEASE) and I have this in my `mvc-config.xml`:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome"/>
```

So requests to "/" are forwarded to the welcome view `welcome.jsp`.

This means in my case, calling the URL `http://myproject-test.mydomain.com/` will forward to the `welcome.jsp`. It's fine, but I have to extend it. Besides the URL `http://myproject-test.mydomain.com/`, I have the URL `http://myproject-anothertest.mydomain.com/`. With this URL, the whole application should be the same, except the welcome page.

Calling `http://myproject-anothertest.mydomain.com/`, I want to have the `welcome-test.jsp` page instead of the `welcome.jsp`.

So, how can I do this? I have to know from which subomain (myproject-test or myproject-anothertest) the user calls the site and then show him welcome.jsp or welcome-test.jsp.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag `<mvc:view-controller>` maps to [ParameterizableViewController](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ParameterizableViewController.html)

You could inherit your own controller class from its parent, [AbstractController](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractController.html), and use the `request` parameter in method `handleRequestInternal` to deduce which hostname is being used to access your page, then use the appropriate view.

HTTP request header `Host` contains (if using HTTP/1.1) the "virtual" server name that is being used to access your page.  Older HTTP/1.0 protocol does not have the Host header, and some proxies map traffic to HTTP/1.0, in that case you will not be able to distinguish between the traffic using different names.

In JSP, you could use `<%=request.getServerName()%>` to access the Host header value.  See doc for [getServerName](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29).

Comment: Isn't there a default way to do this? Or can I switch this in my welcome.jsp page, so I change not the whole page, only the differences in values in the JSP?

Comment: In your JSP, you can use <%= request.getServerName() %>